# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis showing again and again

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me to rectify the error, i have checked all the parenthesis.

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
(
    Fname varchar2(15), 
    Minit char(1), 
    Lname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Ssn char(9) NOT NULL,
    Bdate date(7), 
    Address varchar2(32),
    Sex char(1), 
    Salary number(22), 
    Super_ssn char(9), 
    Dno number(22),

    CONSTRAINT s_con PRIMARY KEY (Super_ssn)
);
```

Comment: Not related to your actual question, but are you sure that the PK of your table should be `Super_ssn`? The naming strongly suggests that it should be `Ssn`.

Answer (score 3):

Sql does not parameterize its `DATE` datatype. Thus use `Bdate date` instead of `Bdate date(7)`.